# Xorg does not show my device in xinput

Tags: xorg, touch-screen

I have a file '51-mitsubishi.conf' which I have created and placed in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ along with the other .conf files that were there already.

When viewing the /var/log/Xorg.0.log there is no mention of my driver or anything related to my conf file.

I understand that the xorg uses 'AutoAddDevices' and that this may be causing the issue, but I have not found a solution for this.

I can see my driver with 'lsmod | grep "mitsubishi", but it says "Used By 0". I should mention that I have the driver added to /etc/modules like so:
lp
mitsubishi_ts_serial
rtc
And the driver starts automatically.

**Xorg seems to be ignoring my device. Any advice on what I should do next to get Xorg to see my device and attach to it?**

Here is the conf file:

```
Section "InputClass" 
Identifier "MitsubishiTouchscreen" 
MatchIsTouchscreen "true" 
EndSection

Section "InputDevice" 
Identifier "MitsubishiTouchscreen" 
Driver "mitsubishi_ts_serial" 
Option "Device" "/dev/ttyUSB0" 
Option "BaudRate" "38400" 
Option "MinX" "0" 
Option "MaxX" "2000" 
Option "MinY" "0" 
Option "MaxY" "2000" 
Option "UntouchDelay" "10" 
Option "ReportDelay" "10" 
Option "SendCoreEvents" "yes" 
Option "ScreenNumber" "0" 
Option "ButtonNumber" "1" 
EndSection
```

Comment: You should have a pointer device corresponding to your touchscreen, check your `/dev/input` directory if your driver is working properly; see if you can find it?

Comment: I do not see it in /dev/input. Question: Does the driver create the /dev/input when it is loaded with modprobe?

Comment: Yes, the driver should create a pointer device (typically for ts drivers). See if you can find it under `/sys` (and if you can, check the driver string). You probably have a device tree binding issue.

Comment: A search of 'find /sys/ -maxdepth 8 -name "*mitsubishi*" -print' produced the following: '/sys/bus/serio/drivers/mitsubishi'    '/sys/module/mitsubishi_ts_serial'   '/sys/module/mitsubishi_ts_serial/drivers/serio:mitsubishi' .

Comment: Are you actually running the serio driver or just loading the module? You should be running some kind of init script to invoke the driver on the correct serial port. Usually with `inputattach` or something similar.

Comment: I am just loading the module. I was hoping xorg would be the one to run the serio driver based on my "InputDevice" section. Since inputattach doesn't have a generic use-case I can't see how I could use it. Any suggestions to run the serio driver? Sorry for the noob questions.

Comment: Since `inputattach` doesn't have a proper tree, I'd recommend adding a new entry to some version the `inputattach` source and compiling it to support your driver. It should be about 5 or 6 lines of code at most. The magic numbers you'll need should be in the touchscreen driver source.

Comment: inputattach was the answer. I added my device to the list of devices and ran the program as sudo user. Originally it did not let me set the line discipline, but running as sudo worked.

Comment: Please write up your solution as answer; comments may not be permanent. Include as many details as necessary. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question, and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, I added my device to the array of 'struct input_types' within inputattach.c. This source file I had to find online. After adding the correct parameters to this list and recompiling, I was then able to start my driver running my own built inputattach file: 
./myInputAttach -mydriver /dev/ttyUSB0

Running a tail -f /var/log/kern.log shows "printk" output from the driver starting and the interrupts.

I still do not see the driver on xinput, but this at least solves the issue of the driver not being used.

Comment: You need to change `Option "Device"` in your xorg conf file to point to the `/dev/input/` device. You will probably have to write an init script to launch input attach on boot (so it gets setup before X starts).

Comment: I changed my xorg to an 'InputClass' section and changed the 'Option "Device"' to 'MatchDevicePath' using /dev/input/event*. It finds my device correctly now, but it says "No input driver specified, ignoring this device".